# How to get date in Julia

Tags: julia

I search the docs but I cannot find a function to get today's date.I probably am missing something fairly obvious.

I just need something like

```
julia> today()
2014-06-25

julia> string(today())
"2014-06-25"
```

Comment: The first Google search result for "julia language today's date" is [this page](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/packages/packagelist/), which led me to [this](https://github.com/quinnj/Datetime.jl), which led me to [this](https://github.com/quinnj/Datetime.jl/wiki/Datetime-Manual), which describes a `today()` function.

Comment: So there's nothing in the standard library? I don't really want to add a package just for one method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your exact sketch now works precisely as you've written it after `using Dates`.  The [Dates](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/#Dates-1) module is a part of the standard library and thus is available by default:

```
julia> using Dates

julia> today()
2020-08-20

julia> string(today())
"2020-08-20"
```

(note: this answer has been edited and updated for version 1.0+; this question pre-dates the existence of the Dates stdlib.)

Comment: This answer is deprecated now, @tiho has the correct answer.

Comment: Edited to remove the answer that was written for — I think — Julia 0.3!

Answer (score 18):

You can now use:

```
julia> Dates.today()
2015-07-15

julia> string(Dates.today())
"2015-07-15"
```

Comment: Remember to load the Dates module before with `using Dates`!