# print current time in Julia

Tags: julia

Is there an elegant way of printing the current time in Julia?

```
println("$(Dates.hour(now())):$(Dates.minute(now()))")
```

would inelegantly and incorrectly print 12.01pm as `12:1`.

Comment: Here , refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416973/how-to-get-date-in-julia

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use `Dates.format` to format your date/times (check [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Working_with_dates_and_times) for formating instructions). For your given example:

```
>>> Dates.format(now(), "HH:MM")  
"13:18"

>>> typeof(ans)
ASCIIString
```

The return of `Dates.format` is a string itself (which is instantly printed in a REPL or you can print it with any printing function).